# Replicating rows in a data frame using information in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

I have the following data frame NewTests:
[image]
The problem: I want to replicate the rows in the data frame using the information in 'duration' column. Although in this case the replication factor is 1 but it can be anything 2,3,4, etc. And in the replicate rows I want to add a new column called as 'Date' which contains information from the PromotionStartDate and PromotionEndDate columns.

E.g. in this case, the Date Column should contain 2017-04-01 for the entries shown. But in another case where duration is 2 and the PromotionStartDatae= 2017-03-01 and PromotionEndDate=2017-05-01, the replicated row 1 should contain 2017-03-01 in Date column and the replicated row 2 should contain 2017-04-01 in Date column.

I am trying to use the following solution to work out my problem:

```
library(splitstackshape)
newConrtols=expandRows(NewTests,"duration",drop=FALSE)%>%
group_by(CustomerNumber,PromotionID,RewardAssigned,RunID,ModelID)%>%
mutate(Date=seq(as.Date(PromotionStartDate),as.Date(PromotionEndDate),by="month")[1:duration])
```

But this gives the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

What am I doing wrong in the solution?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data or give a definition of the dataframe, edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43666764/edit

Comment: Use the `do` instead of `mutate` to do this

Comment: i.e. Perhaps, `%>% mutate_at(vars(PromotionStartDate, PromotionEndDate), as.Date)%>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., Date = seq(.$PromotionStartDate, .$PromotionEndDate, by = "month")))`

Comment: thanks! I am trying it.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple, you just select the right row by using the following example.
Lets say I have a dataframe just like you.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4)
b=c(a,b,c,d)
t=data.frame(a,b)
```

Now, if I want the second column, I would normally type

```
t[2,]
```

Now that I want the second row I will type

```
t[,2]
```

IF I WANT TO copy that in the fifth row I would do

```
t[,5]=t[,2]
```

In your case if wanted to copy the dates from column PromotionDate to FinalDate you could right this line:`your_variable_with_the_dataframe[6,]=your_variable_with_the_dataframe[7,]`

Comment: I think this is not the reason why the OP got the error

Comment: I thought he wanted to duplicate a row and manipulate the data inside.